# Why not infer T::Boolean for true and false?

Tags: sorbet

Sorbet infers the type of `true` to be TrueClass, and the type of `false` to be `FalseClass`. Often it would be nice if it would instead infer `T::Boolean`. Why not special case `true` and `false` to have the type `T::Boolean` instead?

It's possible to work around this problem with a type annotation, initializing variables with `T.let(true, T::Boolean)` for example, but it would be nice to not have to provide this extra information.

```rb
# typed: true

T.reveal_type(true) # Revealed type: `TrueClass`
T.reveal_type(false) # Revealed type: `FalseClass`

extend T::Sig

sig {params(x: T::Boolean).void}
def test(x)
  var = true
  10.times do
    var = false # Changing the type of a variable in a loop is not permitted
  end
end
```

The assignment of `false` to `var` in the loop causes an error to be raised, as the type of `var` is being changed from `TrueClass` to `FalseClass`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorbet's flow-sensitive typing is made more precise by `true` and `false` having different types. In the following example, a variable with the value `true` is used as the condition of an if-statement:

```rb
# typed: true

val = true
if val
  puts "true!"
else
  puts "false?"
end
```

The resulting error from sorbet is:

```
editor.rb:7: This code is unreachable https://srb.help/7006
     7 |  puts "false?"
               ^^^^^^^^
Errors: 1
```

Behind the scenes, sorbet knows that the value being examined has the type `TrueClass`, and that the value `true` is the only value of that type. As a result, it knows that `val` cannot be `false`, and that the `else` branch will never be executed.

Now consider the case where we instead infer the type `T::Boolean` for `true` and `false`. `T::Boolean` is a synonym for `T.any(TrueClass, FalseClass)`, so in the example it now means that `val` could be either `true` or `false`. As a result, it becomes impossible to tell from the type alone that the `else` branch will not be executed.

The [flow-sensitive typing documentation](https://sorbet.org/docs/flow-sensitive) on sorbet.org has more information on this topic.

Comment: Why do you answer your own question?

Comment: @PavelEvstigneev: nothing wrong with that. Having seen the question, I realized I didn't know the answer. It's a useful Q/A.

Answer (score 0):

Asked the same question today as well.
Ended up fixing it as you suggested with type annotations and initializing with `T.let(true, T::Boolean)`

```
# typed: true
extend T::Sig

sig {params(x: T::Boolean).void}
def test(x)
  var = T.let(true, T::Boolean)
  10.times do
    var = T.let(false, T::Boolean)
  end
end
```